# Cassandra write strategy

Tags: cassandra

I want to write 1 billions rows with 2 connected nodes in Cassandra. I use 8 threads from the clients but I don't know whether I write only in one node or both to have the max performance?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't matter if you write to one node or both. Whichever node is receiving the updates (called the coordinator node) will partition the data based on the partitioner and distribute the necessary section of data to the other node. So whether the updates goes to 1 node or 2, the same network latency and processing will be carried out overall.

With 8 threads you should see good write performance, as Cassandra is optimized for a write heavy workload.

Here is a good treatment of [client requests](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/about_client_requests).